# Having a html element stay in the same position without using position: fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

To show what I want to do, here is a url. http://octopuscreative.com .

I want something that when I scroll down the height, the cyan div disappears like the website above.

I currently have the scrolling working in my code, however, I cannot see the rest of my HTML that is below my **#main div**. I don't know if this has anything to do with my new **#slideshow div** (with a fixed position).
I thought since the **#slideshow div** had its `height` reduced to `0`, I would be able to see the HTML underneath the **#main div**, but all I see below is white.

```
var header = $('#slideshow'),
headerH = header.height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
if (header.height() >= 0) {
    header.css({
        height: -($(this).scrollTop() - headerH), position: 'absolute'
    });
}
else if (header.height() < 0 ) {
header.css('height', 0);
header.css('position', 'absolute');
}
});


    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="top">

        <div id="stallion">
            <img id="stallionpic" src="stallion1.png" />
            <h1 class="h1">Stallion Stride</h1>
            <div id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="google.com" id="first">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Register</a></li>
                <li><a href="" id="last">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="slideshow">
            <div id="leftbutton"></div>
            <div id="rightbutton"></div>
            <div id="slideshownav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="active"></a></li>
                    <li><a></a></li>
                    <li><a></a></li>
                    <li><a></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <div id="slideshow_inner">

            <li id="pic1"><a><img src="pic2.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li id="pic2"><a><img src="pic1.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li id="pic3"><a><img src="pic3.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li id="pic4"><a><img src="pic4.jpg" /></a></li>

        </div>
        <p>a;lsdfja;lskdjf;laskdjf;aslkdjf;alsdjkfa;sldfkja;sldkfja;sldkfja;</p>
        </div>

        <div id="mainContent">
            <p>a;lsdfja;lskdjf;laskdjf;aslkdjf;alsdjkfa;sldfkja;sldkfja;sldkfja;</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Where is your code, man?! Give us your code!

Comment: I have probably about 500 lines of code between the Jquery, css, and html so I didn't know what to post at first.  I thought the solution was gonna be more conceptual than anything so thats why I didn't post anything

Comment: basically what I want to know is the url I posted above how would someone go about making that.  I am just looking for a general explanation.  Cause what I did is I made the header and my image both fixed and I made the image height shrink as the user scrolled down thinking that any additional html would show after the imaged that had its position fixed had its height as 0 but that has not worked.

Comment: then… have you tried looking at their code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the lead dev at Octopus. Here's the bare minimum amount of code to make something like that header effect work (it does use fixed position).

#### HTML

```
<div id="hero">
    <h2>I am the hero</h2>
</div>
<div id="main-content">
    <h3>I am the main content</h3>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

div#hero {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #3D6AA2;
    height: 300px;
}

div#main-content {
    height: 1500px;
    background: #fff;
    margin-top: 300px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I also threw together a jsFiddle that demonstrates it, along with the bit of parallax stuff the site does: http://jsfiddle.net/paulstraw/FW4FF/

Hope that helps!

Comment: I was on the right track but I forgot any html element I put after a fixed header would be behind it so I had to make an empty placeholder that had the height of the header but thanks for the answer and your website looks awesome

Answer (score 1):

`position: fixed;` positions the element based on viewable screen coordinates, so when you scroll, the position will update to reflect the 'new' top/left boundaries. `position: absolute;` is more like what you are describing, it will keep the element in the same place, regardless of the content around it, or the browser's scroll position. However, this will take the element out of the 'flow' of the page, and other elements will act like it is not there (and might overlap it). In which case, you will likely have more luck just `float`ing your header left: `float: left;`.

If you do this, you will probably need to clear the floats in your `main` div by adding the css style: `clear: both;`. This will push the `main` div below any floated content above.